# Get Current URL of page in javascript, thats works on tablet

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link, when i press it then i get to twitter/facebook or linkedin, so I can share a news.

When i then have shared the news, and close the popup, then im back on my page, but then i can see that it have redirect to my first page bc of href="#" in my javascript, so thats ok.

But i want it to be on the page, I clicked the link. so if the page is

> www.mydomain.com/blog/news/3/

Then i want my link to ref to that link in href=" ", but how do I do that in javascript so it also works on tablets ?

My javascript code for facebook is.

```
    $('#facebook').sharrre({
      share: {
        facebook: true
      },
      template: '<a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>{total}</a>',
      enableHover: false,
      enableTracking: true,
      click: function(api, options){
        api.simulateClick();
        api.openPopup('facebook');
      }
    });
```

How do I get the current page URL to the # in a href inside a javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pull the URL using `document.URL` and store this into a variable to pass into your `sharrre()` method:

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#facebook').sharrre({
    template: '<a href="' + url + '"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>{total}</a>',
    ...
});
```

This should work fine on tablets.